# Erro de "expected expression before ‘int’"

Tags: c

Estava seguindo este exemplo, mas foi feito no Windows, então foi usado `<conio.h>`. Quando tento rodar no Linux recebo 2 erros: um em `*h=int(tempo);`,  que não entendo porquê, e o outro no `getch`. Como posso substitui-los?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void horario(float tempo, int *h, int *m)
{
    *h=int(tempo);
    *m=(tempo-*h)*60;
}

int main ()
{
    int hora,minuto;
    char resp;
    float t;

    do
    {
        printf("Digite o horario na forma centesimal: ");
        scanf("%f",&t);
        horario(t,&hora,&minuto);
        printf("Horario: %02d:02%d\n",hora,minuto);
        printf("Quer calcular outro horario? (S/N):");
        resp=getch();
    } while (resp=='S');
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aqui é o StackOverflow **em Português**. Favor usar esse idioma ao fazer perguntas, e não o inglês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tinha dois problemas:

1. Typecast mal feito.
2. getchar em vez de getch

   ```
   void horario(float tempo, int *h, int *m){
       *h=(int)tempo;
       *m=(tempo-*h)*60;
   }

   int main(){
       int hora,minuto;
       char resp;
       float t;
       do
       {
           printf("Digite o horario na forma centesimal: ");
           scanf("%f",&t);
           horario(t,&hora,&minuto);
           printf("Horario: %02d:02%d\n",hora,minuto);
           printf("Quer calcular outro horario? (S/N):");
           getchar();
           resp = getchar();
       } while (resp=='S');
       getchar();
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Quando rodo o programa, o "do ... while" não esta recomeçando, sera algum problema com o getchar?

Comment: Sim. O `getchar()` apanha o ENTER do `scanf()` anterior. Uma solucao grosseira sera fazeres 2 `getchar()` seguidos: um para consumir o ENTER e outro para apanhar a resposta.

Comment: Ou então usa um scanf("%c", &resp);

Comment: entendi, eu acho que para esse exemplo vou usar o scanf mesmo, muito obrigado.

Comment: Já editei o meu código, como @pmg disse tem que usar dois getchar() ou então um scanf("%s") acho que também funciona.

Comment: No scanf coloque um espaço para ignorar eventuais \n existentes no buffer de entrada: scanf(" %c", &resp);

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer um "cast" usa o tipo desejado entre parentesis seguido do valor

```
(int)tempo // cast de tempo para tipo int: correcto
int(tempo) // incorrecto: aparenta ser a chamada da funcao int com argumento tempo
```

---

Podes substituir o `getch()` por `getchar()` (prototipo em `<stdio.h>` que ja incluiste).

Comment: a sim, eu confundi mesmo, muito obrigado. você conhece uma função que substitua o getch no linux?

Comment: Note-se que `int(valor)` funciona em C++. Talvez o código tenha sido compilado em modo C++ em Windows?

Comment: não, eu acho que foi apenas um erro de digitação, este foi um exemplo dado em aula, e usamos C.